# Jquery set href from another link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i've this problem:

I've made this line of code to add a link to a image :

`$('.atbd-thumbnail-card-front-wrap > img').wrap("<a class='imglink' href=''></a>");`

is working fine but i need to put the url from another link in that href thatlink has this structure:

```
<div class="atbd_listing_data_list">
 <ul>
  <li><p><span>icon</span><a href="this is the one i need">text</a></p></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

It can't be a static url because there will be several divs like the one above, how can i do that in Jquery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you give us more information about the structure you are working with, for example what is the relationship between the `atbd-thumbnail-card-front-wrap img` and the `a` element that has the link you want to use - is there only one of each, or if there are more on the page, how do you choose which to use?

Comment: Hey, thnx for your answer  ```atbd-thumbnail-card-front-wrap``` is the only identifier i've because i'm using a plugin to make a directory list, so i've to call that class and from ther find the image and make it a link, the ```a``` element is the url from the client that i'm listing, but i need that link in the image [link]https://rivieramayaenunclick.com/bares-restaurantes-y-antojitos/ this is the url that i'm doing, if you click on "Restaurantes" you'll see the image and link that i'm talking about

Comment: if you can make a small fiddle to create minimal reproducible code of what you are trying to achieve then folks here will be able to help better.